# Uploading multiple scripts in ORACLE 11g express edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I have googled and searched but can not find a concrete answer for what I am trying to do, I have approx 25 scripts which I need to import

[image]

When I am in the `SQL WORKSHOP` I have the option to upload scripts, but **it only allows me to upload a single script at a time.**

[image]

Needless to say, there should be (is) a more efficient / different way of doing this, allowing the user to upload multiple, scripts, hench my question...***How to upload multiple scripts in Oracle Express Edition?***

Many Thanks

Comment: What are those scripts? Is it a data you need to import into a database? And in which platform you are trying to do, linux or windows?

Comment: They are `sql` scripts, to be imported into DB. Im running Windows

Comment: i think it only allows upload one a t a tim.e Can you combine them into one file?

Comment: For now, you will have to upload them one at a time. According to the Apex Feature Request ACFI, it has been targeted for Apex 5.1 https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=55447 but haven't seen it in the Early Adopter yet.

Comment: Rge way tio script Oracle is use the command line sqlplus.exe (but I don't know if that is in Express edition)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp add your comment as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score -2):

Best thing you can do is use SQL Developer .